# How to build the Apple's library with the SSL bug intact?

Tags: macos, security, ssl

How can I build the library with the now-famous [SSL bug](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-1266) that came to light in February 2014?

I've seen [this](https://www.imperialviolet.org/2014/02/22/applebug.html) article, which has a link to the [vulnerable version of sslKeyExchange.c source file](http://opensource.apple.com/source/Security/Security-55471/libsecurity_ssl/lib/sslKeyExchange.c), but it's not clear to me where is the build script (Makefile, Xcode project, whatever) that I can use to build this library.

I'd like to run a static code analyzer on it, and do to that properly I need to build it.

Comment: That code base gets incorporated on iOS and OS X. Which architecture are you looking to compile the core OS? (and no matter what answer, I'm tempted to migrate this to Stack Overflow since software development isn't precisely on topic here. However, we do entertain compiling open-source software questions on OS X and there is some overlap in scope). Would you object to this moving to Stack Exchange or do you feel it's best left here?

Comment: I want to compile the lib on OS X. Stack Overflow has huge readership so that might be beneficial; I don't know which place would have more people that could answer my question. That place is where I'd like it to reside :-)

Comment: If for some reason the SO community doesn't want this, we'd be happy to host it again on Ask Different, but it will likely get a more technical answer here.